# Check each value inside a nested array of a dictionary Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, dictionary

I know this question might seem obvious to some, but i can't get around a proper solution.

I have a dictionary

```
someDict = [String : [Int]]
```

Also i have an Integer variable and a string

```
var someNumber = Int()
var someString = String()
```

My goal is to compare if `someString = someDict key` and if yes - compare every Int value inside it's nested array to `someNumber` (check whether it's smaller or bigger and give some output).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you look for the key in the dictionary that matches the one you're after — so we loop through all the keys.

Then, once we find a match, we loop through all the contents of that keys value. In this case, its our array of numbers.

```
let someDict = ["matchingString" : [6,7,5,4]]

var someNumber = 5
var someString = "matchingString"

for (someDictKey, numbers) in someDict {
    if someDictKey == someString {
        // Key Found
        for number in numbers {
            if number == someNumber {
                // Number Found
            } else {
                // no matching number found
            }
        }
    } else {
        // No matching key found
    }
}
```

Try it in a playground.

Comment: Note that if we're dealing with a huge dictionary, this kind of defeats the purpose of dictionaries hash value lookup (looping over all dictionary entries when we can just attempt to access the key directly).

Comment: You're absolutely right, and I actually like your solution a lot more. Much cleaner and faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of optional chaining, without the need to explicitly loop over the dictionary entries.

```
var someDict = [String : [Int]]()
someDict["SomeString"] = [Int](1...5)

let someString = "SomeString"
let someNumber = 2

if someDict[someString]?.contains(someNumber) ?? false {
    print("Dict value array for key '\(someString)' contains value \(someNumber).")
}
else {
    print("Dict value array for key '\(someString)' does not contain value \(someNumber).")
}
/* Prints: Dict value array for key 'SomeString' contains value 2. */
```

If we're dealing with a huge dictionary, looping over all dictionary entries kind of defeats the purpose of dictionaries `O(1)` hash value lookup (i.e., just attempting to access the key directly).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var someDict = [String : [Int]]()

someDict["a"] = [1, 2, 3]
someDict["b"] = [4, 5, 6]

var str = "a"
var number = 3

for (key, value) in someDict {
    if key == str {
        for num in value {
            if num == number {
                print("matched")
            } else {
                print("Oops")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("nope")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply ask the dictionary for the key you're interested into, and enumerate within the corresponding object:

```
// this helps us get rid of having to unwrap someDict["someString"] first 
for intVal in someDict["someString"] ?? [Int]() {
    print(intVal < someNumber ? "smaller" : "not smaller")
}
```

Or, if your interested on finding the numbers smaller that `someNumber`, you can use the filtering support:

```
let smallerNumbers = (someDict[someString] ?? [Int]()).filter({$0 < someNumber})
```

Comment: Note that you needn't explicitly state the type of the empty array in the nil coalescing part above (`someDict[someString] ?? [] ...` works just as fine). Alternatively use optional chaining for `nil` return for non-existing key (`let smallerNumbers = someDict[someString]?.filter({$0 < someNumber})`).

Comment: @dfri, yes, you're right, the compiler can infer the appropriate type in this case